# GIT Best practice for newly created branches

Tags: git, github

I'm new to GIT and tried initially to find an answer for this on the forum but my searching skills might need some improvements ^^

Let's say we have **main remote repo** and we have cloned it on our local (this creates **main local repo** and **origin/main** repo (for tracking the remote changes)

At some time somebody creates a new branch -**feature1**- (based on the commit ID from **MAIN repo**) from the GitHub console:

Q: What is a best practice to update my local repo with the most recent changes (creation of a new branch)

The only way that I found (don't know if this is a best practice) is the following:

- create locally a new branch with the same name as the new one

> git checkout -b feature1

- do the necessary changes (edit/add files) -> add them to staging area -> commit
- if you do git push you get the following message

> fatal: The current branch feature1 has no upstream branch. To push the
> current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
>
> ```
> git push --set-upstream origin feature1
> ```

- after you run the above command and setup the upstream you can successfully push the changes to the **remote feature1 repo**

And at the end after you do a PR you must delete the **feature1 repo** (remotely and locally)

**Remote**: via Github console

**Local**:

> git branch -d feature1 = to delete feature1 branch
>
> git branch --delete --remotes origin/feature1 = to delete the remote
> tracking feature1 branch

Please let me know if this is the right approach or am I missing something.

Comment: Simpler to do `git fetch; git checkout feature1`, it'll create the branch and set its upstream (if same name branch exists on remote).

Comment: Side note: Git is not an acronym, so it shouldn't be in all-caps.

Answer (score 1):

"Best practice" questions are almost automatically off-topic on StackOverflow, as "best" is a matter of opinion.

It's clear from your question, though, that you haven't really [grokked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok) Git's model.  The fact is, you can (very painfully, mind you) work in Git with *no branch names at all*.  What matter in Git is not branch names, but rather *commits*.  The purpose of any one branch name is to help you—and Git—*find* the commits you want.

To this end, each repository has its own set of branch names.  Your branch names will help you find the commits *you* care about.  Their branch names—whoever "they" are: in this case, I mean the Git repository over on `origin`—help *them* find the commits *they* care about.

When you and they both care especially-much about some particular commit, you and they will generally both have some sort of name(s) for that commit.  But your name *does not have to match their name* in any way.  It can be any name you find meaningful.

Humans being human, we often find it helpful to use the same name in both repositories.  That's fine, and Git does make that easy for you.

You're using unusual terminology here too.  Let's define the Git terminology properly:

- A *repository* is a collection of commits, stored in Git's *object database* (which is a simple [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database) where the keys are commit hash IDs), plus a separate database—another key-value one—of *names*, such as branch and tag names.  The names database means that you aren't forced to memorize a bunch of raw Git hash IDs.

  Most repositories also include a *working tree*, which is where you do your work.  Although the repository provides a working tree, *none of the files in the working tree are in the repository itself*.  The way Git normally implements this is to store the repository proper within a hidden directory / folder (whichever term you prefer) named `.git` at the top level of the working tree.  (However, a *bare* repository omits the working tree, so this storage format gets modified there.)
- A *hash ID* (or more formally, an *object ID* or OID) is the magic by which Git manages the sharing of commits.  Git stores these commits—plus other objects that are needed to make the commits actually useful—in that object database.  When you clone a repository, you're making a copy of the objects database—but *not* a copy of the names database!  Each commit has a *unique* hash ID.  This allows two Git repositories to get together and decide whether they have the same commits just by comparing hash IDs.  If one database is missing some hash ID, it is missing that commit (or other object): that Git repository can *get* the commit (or other object) from the repository that has it.

  Somehow, even without communicating with any other Git repository—remember that Git works even if you're off-line—creating a *new* commit gives that new commit a *unique* hash ID that has never been used before in any Git repository, and will never be used again in any other Git repository *unless* it is to store *that commit*.  That's why these OIDs are so magic.  We can prove that this particular magic is mathematically impossible, and someday Git will fail, but the sheer size of hash IDs puts this day far in the future: enough billions of years, we hope, that nobody will care.
- A *branch name* is a particular kind of name (as compared to, e.g., a tag name) that allows you (or Git) to get the hash ID of the *last* commit in the branch.  Git calls this the *tip commit*.  You are also allowed—and in fact strongly encouraged—to be "on" one branch name at almost all times: being "on" a branch affects, in a small way, the way Git makes a *new* commit.
- A *remote* like `origin` is just a short name in which Git stores the URL for another Git repository, plus some other useful data.

Because a `remote` like origin *refers to* some other Git repository, and that other Git repository *is* a Git repository, that repository has its own object and names databases.  As you and they add new commits, your clone and their clone drift apart.  Note that you never directly *remove* a commit, although certain operations can "rewrite" old (and presumably lousy) commits to become new and improved, different commits, after which the old commits *may* eventually be cleaned out—but this never happens right away.  So, every now and then, you'll need to reconnect your repository to their repository.  You do this with `git fetch` ("get commits from them") and `git push` ("give commits to them").

#### What to know about commits

Besides its unique hash ID, by which Git finds a commit (or, if you don't have the commit, finds that you *don't* have it), you need to know this about commits:

- They're strictly read-only.  No part of any commit can ever change.  This is necessary for the numbering scheme.  (If a commit could change, without changing hash IDs, the whole idea of just comparing hash IDs alone would fall apart.)
- Every commit contains a *full snapshot of every file*, or rather, every file that Git knew about at the time you (or whoever) made the commit.  The files *in* the commit are stored indirectly, in a special compressed and *de-duplicated* form, so that any one version of any file content only appears *once* in the all-objects database.  This means the repository does not grow enormously fat just because every commit stores every file: in fact, most commits are *tiny*.  Even new content, which requires a new internal *blob object* to store it, is (eventually and usually) super-compressed (though it's initially stored more loosely compressed as a "loose object", vs the packed objects that are super-compressed).
- Every commit stores some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This metadata includes things like the name and email address of the person who made the commit (taken from your `user.name` and `user.email` settings, which you can set however you like: Git does not check these at all; they're never used for authentication).  It includes some date-and-time-stamps and so on as well.

Crucially for Git's own operation, the metadata in any one commit includes a *list of previous commit hash IDs*.  This list is usually one entry long, making what Git calls an *ordinary commit*.  (The unusual cases are the very first commit ever, which has an empty list because there is no previous commit, and *merge* commits, which generally have two previous commits, but Git allows any list of at least 2 here.)

It's this list, where each ordinary commit points backwards to one earlier commit that Git calls its *parent*, that makes up something that humans call a "branch".  But note that humans also call a *branch name* a "branch", and sometimes call multiple other things "branch" as well.  This makes the word "branch" kind of meaningless in Git: you often have to guess at what someone who said "branch" actually meant (if they even knew, themselves).

Every now and then, you should think about this list.  If it helps, try drawing a picture.  Here, I'll draw a picture of some commits, using uppercase letters to stand in for their real hash IDs (which are big and horrible and impossible for humans to deal with):

... <-F <-G <-H

In this drawing, `H` is our *most recent* or "last" commit.  It is the one that Git calls the *tip commit* of the branch (with the word *branch* meaning "this list of commits ending at commit `H`).

Commit `H` stores, in its metadata, the hash ID of its *parent* commit, for which I'm using the letter `G`.  We say that commit `H` *points to* commit `G`.  But commit `G` is an ordinary commit too, so it points to *its* parent `F`.  Commit `F`, being an ordinary commit, points backwards to yet another commit.

It's this chain of commits, starting at the tip and working backwards, that makes a "branch" in Git—well, one kind of "branch", again; the poor word "branch" gets beaten to death here.  We normally want a *branch name* for this tip commit, so we make one:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

Here, the name `main` *points to* commit `H`, and `H` points back to `G` and so on.  Using the name `main` tells Git that we'd like to do something with commit `H`.

We can have *more than one name* attached to any one commit:

```
...--G--H   <-- feature1, main
```

Here we have two branch names, *both of which select commit `H`*.  We can create or delete any branch name at any time: Git's only requirement for a branch name is that it must *point to some commit*.  If we like, we can make a name pointing to `G`:

```
...--G   <-- older
      \
       H   <-- feature1, main
```

Commits `G` and `H` have not changed in any way—I just had to draw `H` on a separate line to make `older` point to `G` here.  (On a whiteboard, you can have your arrows bend around in circles or whatever, but I'm constrained by the text medium.)  Note that adding a new name didn't change the fact that commit `G` is "on" the `main` and `feature1` branches either: that commit and the earlier ones are now on *three* branches.

Deleting a branch name decreases the number of branches that its tip commit and earlier commits are "on", and if we delete the *last* name that can find *any* of these commits, we "lose" the commits.  They're still there, in the all-objects database, but if we don't know their hash IDs, we won't be able to find them!  (So don't delete the last name by which you can find some commit.)

Using `git log` on a branch name, Git will start with the tip commit—the one the name selects—and then work backwards.  So we don't *need* a name for earlier commits.  We only need a name for the *last* commit, to make it easy for us (and Git) to find it, without having to memorize hash IDs.

#### Remote-tracking names

When we *clone* a repository, with `git clone`, we get:

- a full copy of all of the objects, and
- a new, mostly-empty *names* database.

Our Git software will take each of their Git repository's *branch names* and *change those names*.  Git constructs these new names by sticking the name of the remote in front of the branch name.<sup>1</sup>  Their `main` becomes your `origin/main`, for instance.  This keeps their *branch* names separate: you make *your own* `main`, and your own `feature1` if you like.

The `git clone` command actually uses the same code as `git fetch` here (at one time, `git clone` was a shell script that just ran other commands).  So after you've run `git clone`, if you think the other Git repository—the one over at `origin`—has acquired new commits and/or new branch names, you just run `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`, and your Git calls up their software, using the stored URL, and checks.  For any new *branch names* they have, your Git will create new remote-tracking names.  First, for any new *commits* they have, your Git will download their commits, adding to your all-objects database.  (This is safe since their commits have *unique* hash IDs, that are always different from any new commits *you* have made.)  Then your Git create or updates your remote-tracking names, based on their branch names.

Note that by default, your Git doesn't *clean up left over remote-tracking names*.  That is, if they *had* a branch named `zorg` and your software created an `origin/zorg`, and they have *deleted* their `zorg`, your `origin/zorg` remains as a stale left-over.  To clean these out, run `git fetch origin --prune` or `git remote prune origin`.  (To have `git fetch` clean them out for you automatically, set `fetch.prune` to `true`.  I do this in my global Git config.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, the remote-tracking names are in an entirely separate [*namespace*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace), as they start with `refs/remotes/` rather than `refs/heads/`.  But Git normally strips off the `refs/remotes/` or `refs/heads/` part—except for `git branch -a`, which only strips off `refs/` from the remote-tracking names, for reasons I've never seen explained and can only guess at.

Git calls these things *remote-tracking branch names*, unnecessarily loading up the word "branch" even more.  I use *remote-tracking name* because you can't get "on" one of these, so they're clearly not actually *branch* names; see the next section.

---

#### Being "on a branch"

We use `git switch` (or, in Git versions before Git 2.23, `git checkout`; it still works, but it's probably best to gradually use the new `git switch`) to change which branch we are "on", in Git.  Let's say we have our two branches, both ending at commit `H`, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- feature1, main
```

Running `git switch main` tells Git that we'd like to use commit `H` as the *current commit*, but not only that: we would also like the *current branch name* to be `main`:

```
...--G--H   <-- feature1, main (HEAD)
```

This "attaches" the special name `HEAD`, written in all uppercase like this, to the chosen branch name.  If we `git switch feature1` we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- feature1 (HEAD), main
```

We are still *using commit `H`* but now we are doing it *through the name `feature1`*.

When we make a *new* commit—by means I won't cover here, except that it involves running `git commit`—Git will make a new frozen-for-all-time snapshot with whatever updates we've made.  This new snapshot goes into a new *commit*, which gets new metadata: our name, the current date-and-time, and so on.  This also saves away the new commit's *parent*.

The parent hash ID that goes into the new commit's metadata is the commit that we have been using: commit `H`.  So the new commit, whatever its random-looking hash ID might turn out to be—this is unpredictable; it depends on every bit of (meta)data in the commit including the exact second at which we make it—will point backwards to `H`, like this:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I
```

The special, clever trick that Git pulls here is that because we're *on* one of the two branches—whichever one it is—Git now *writes commit `I`'s new unique hash ID into that branch name*.  So if we are "on" branch `feature1`, we get this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
```

The name `HEAD` remains attached to the current branch name, but the current branch name now points to a new tip commit.

We are, at this point, the only Git repository in the universe with a commit with `I`'s hash ID.  Nonetheless, commit `I`'s hash ID is now reserved to *this new commit we just made*, forever, so that it will be unique.  This is the magical part of Git.

#### `git push`

If we'd like to *send our new commit to some other Git repository*, we can use `git push`.  We run:

```
git push origin feature1
```

with `origin` being the *remote*, which holds the URL for the other Git repository, and `feature1` identifying the *commit we'd like to send*.  Our Git software calls up their Git software and lists the commit hash ID.  Since it's new, they obviously won't have it: they will say *yes, send me that commit*.  Our Git is then obliged to offer commit `H`, which is `I`'s parent, but we got `H` from them in the first place, so they will say *no thanks, I already have that one*.

That's how our Git software knows that commit `I` is new, and `H` is not.  Our Git now packages up commit `I` and any files or other objects needed *for* commit `I`, minus any that it's sure they have already because they have commit `H`, and sends those over.  They stick all that in their repository's all-objects database<sup>2</sup>, and now they have commit `I`.  But: they have no *branch name*, yet, to remember commit `I`.

Our `git push` then ends with a polite request: *Please, if it's OK, create or update your branch name ________ to point to the tip commit `I`*.  Our Git fills in this branch name with `feature1` *by default*.  We can, if we like, choose some other branch name—but to make things convenient, our Git will use the same name in both repositories *by default*.

If they don't have a `feature1` yet, or if adding commit `I` to their existing `feature1` just *adds commits* the way `git commit` would, they will generally accept this request.<sup>3</sup>

But if they *do* have a `feature1` and it points to some other commit:

```
...--G--H   <-- main [on origin]
         \
          J   <-- feature1 [on origin]
```

then our request to make the name point to `I` instead will make their repository "lose" the hash ID for commit `J`, and they will say no.  This comes back as a weird-looking error (`non-fast-forward`), but it means "I can't do that as I will lose some of *my* commits".

---

<sup>2</sup>Technically, new objects go into a quarantine area first, and only migrate into the main repository later, if the new commits are accepted.  This makes no difference to how you *use* Git, though.

<sup>3</sup>Hosting sites like GitHub add a bunch of controls here: protected branches, permissions, and the like.  Note that these hosting sites also have some mechanism to decide who you are claiming to be, and whether you are in fact that person or program or whatever.  *All* of this is done outside Git proper: Git plays no part in the authentication and verification process here.

---

#### `git fetch` (again) and `git merge` or `git rebase`

To prevent this kind of problem from occurring in the first place, before we go about creating our own `feature1`, we can *check to see if they have one*.  We'll run:

```
git fetch origin
```

and if they have a new commit `J` (remember, commit `I` does not exist yet) and a name `feature1` pointing to it, we'll get this in our repository:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
         \
          J   <-- origin/feature1
```

We'll see `fetch` messages telling us that it got some new commit(s) and created a new remote-tracking name.  (Since remote-tracking names were invented *after* `git fetch`, the messages here are confusing.)

We can now create our own `feature1` branch *using our `origin/feature1` name*.  Both `git switch` (the new way) and `git checkout` (the old one) have a "guessing" feature, where you run:

```
git checkout feature1
```

This *would* give an error—we don't have a branch named `feature1`—but before it does, Git effectively says to itself: *wait, I've been told to guess* (`--guess` is the default) *so I should check for an origin/feature1 or similar*.  Upon finding that one name, our Git says: *Aha, you mean I should create a **new** `feature1` pointing to the same commit* and does that and then switches to it:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          J   <-- feature1 (HEAD), origin/feature1
```

We're now ready to create new commit `I` as before:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          J   <-- origin/feature1
           \
            I   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
```

and we can `git push` our commit `I`.

But: what if we forget?  Or, worse, what if we run `git fetch` and they don't have a `feature1`, and then we make our own and make commit `I` and *while we are doing that* they acquire *their own* `feature1` and commit `J`?

Either way, we end up with this:

```
          I   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   [main etc are here but I'm going to stop drawing them]
         \
          J   <-- origin/feature1
```

It's now *our responsibility* to do something about this.

We have a choice: we can *merge* commits `I` and `J` to make a new *merge commit*, with two parents, which will look like this:

```
          I
         / \
...--G--H   M   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
         \ /
          J   <-- origin/feature1
```

Or, we can use `git rebase` to copy our existing `I` commit to a new-and-improved `I'` whose main difference from `I` is that it adds on to commit `J`:

```
          I   [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H
         \
          J   <-- origin/feature1
           \
            I'  <-- feature1 (HEAD)
```

The merge method is simpler, and is what beginners might wish to start with; many people prefer the rebase method, for whatever reason.  Both methods work fine and which one(s) to use, under which condition(s), are a matter of opinion.

I'm going to omit all the details about how these commands work, and just mention one last thing: there's a `git pull` command, and it means:

1. run `git fetch`, then (assuming that worked)
2. run either `git merge` or `git rebase`

It's your choice as to which command to run in step 2, and there's a lot of stuff to know about this.  I always recommend that newbies to Git practice with separate `git fetch` and second-command, so that they *know* what they're doing, until it becomes familiar enough.  The second command you use affects *what you do to fix things up when the second command goes wrong*, which it will (eventually, if not right away).  Using the `git pull` convenience wrapper does not help with the "fix things up" part, and unless you know exactly *which* second command you *got*, you'll be in trouble at this point.